# receive multicasts with PHP7 on Raspberry

Tags: php, debian, raspberry-pi2, multicast, php-7

I send multicast via PHP (v7.0.8-5) this looking good so far.
[image: the capurted packed, on second PC without Firewall]

*My Problem is i am not able to receive the pakets.*

**CODE IS GOOD, working without Firewall**

this is the code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mesg = "123456789012" ; //the msg i want to send

$ip = "228.5.6.7"; //the ip to send
$port = 14446 ;    //the port to send

//build the socket
$grpparms = array("group"=>$ip,"interface"=>"eth0") ;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_set_option($sock,IPPROTO_IP,MCAST_JOIN_GROUP,$grpparms);   

if($argv[1] == 'r'){ //read multicasts
    $from = '';
    $dest_port = 0;

    $binded = socket_bind($sock, '0.0.0.0',$port);
    socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $dest_port);
    echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $dest_port" . PHP_EOL;
}
if ($argv[1] =='w'){ //write multicasts
    socket_sendto($sock, $mesg, strlen($mesg), 0, $ip,$port);
    echo "Send '$mesg' to $ip at port $port".PHP_EOL;
    socket_close($sock) ;
}
?>
```

I call it with the paramter 'r' to read/receive and with 'w' to send/write multicasts.

I start this script over ssh on two different raspberrys (Vers. 2b) on the same switch. One with 'r' and the other with 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it myself right now, but change `$dest_port` in `socket_recvfrom()` to `$port` or change the value of `$dest_port` from `0` to `14446` and try again please.

Comment: I found the misstake, it was the firewall. the upstanding code is correct.